# Computing or upper bounding a complicated integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

I am stuck in trying to compute or more realistically upper bound the following double integral
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\exp(-(x-a)^2)\exp(-(y-a)^2)}{1+\exp(-x^2)+\exp(-y^2)}dxdy
$$
as a function of $a$. Of course a trivial (and $a$-independent) bound can be obtained via
$$
\frac{1}{1+\exp(-x^2)+\exp(-y^2)}\leq 1
$$
and then solving the resulting double integral closed form, but I was hoping in something better than that. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote your integral by $I$. The described estimate gives $I\le \pi$. More accurately, we have
$$
\pi - I =  \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(x - a)^2 - (y - a)^2}\frac{e^{-x^2} + e^{-y^2}}{1 + e^{-x^2} + e^{-y^2}}\,dx\,dy.
$$
Since $0 < e^{-x^2} + e^{-y^2}\le 2$ we can write
$$
\iint_{\Pi}e^{-(x - a)^2 - (y - a)^2}(e^{-x^2} + e^{-y^2})\,dx\,dy\ge \pi - I \ge \iint_{\Pi}e^{-(x - a)^2 - (y - a)^2}\frac{e^{-x^2} + e^{-y^2}}{3}\,dx\,dy.
$$
The integrals in the latter inequalities can be calculated explicitly giving
$$
\pi - I \approx\exp(-a^2/2)
$$
up to some multiplicative constant.

Comment: I guess the error term is of order $e^{-a^2/2}$, but otherwise it is a nice approach!

Comment: You are right! Fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really appreciated!
By any chance, can I also ask you to give a look at this follow-up question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785629/multiple-integral-upper-bound-with-nice-behaviour ?

Answer (score 4):

Let $I$ denote OP's integral. Extending @Pavel Gubkin's computation, for any integer $N \geq 1$ we have

\begin{align*}
I
&= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (-1)^n \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-(x-a)^2-(y-a)^2} (e^{-x^2} + e^{-y^2})^n \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y + R_N \\
&= \pi \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (-1)^n \sum_{\substack{j,k\geq 0 \\j+k = n}} \frac{n!}{j!k!} \frac{e^{-(\frac{j}{j+1}+\frac{k}{k+1})a^2}}{\sqrt{j+1}\sqrt{k+1}} + R_N, \\
\end{align*}

where the remainder $R_N = (-1)^N \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-(x-a)^2-(y-a)^2} \frac{(e^{-x^2} + e^{-y^2})^N}{1 + e^{-x^2} + e^{-y^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ is bounded by

\begin{align*}
|R_N|
\leq \sum_{\substack{j,k\geq 0 \\j+k = N}} \frac{N!}{j!k!} \frac{e^{-(\frac{j}{j+1}+\frac{k}{k+1})a^2}}{\sqrt{j+1}\sqrt{k+1}}
\leq \frac{2^N}{\sqrt{N+1}}e^{-\frac{N}{N+1}a^2}.
\end{align*}

For instance, $N = 2$ gives

$$ I = \pi \Bigl(1 - \sqrt{2} e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}} \Bigr) + R_2 \qquad\text{with}\qquad 0 \leq R_2 \leq \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}} e^{-\frac{2}{3}a^2}. $$

Comment: Many thanks Sangchul Lee. Both your answers were very helpful for me, and I am very grateful. I picked Pavel Gubkin's as best because in a sense this is an extension of his approach, that came in slightly before yours. Not sure if this makes sense as a motivation... I couldn't really decide which one to pick...
Anyway, can I ask you to give a look at this follow up question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785629/multiple-integral-upper-bound-with-nice-behaviour

Comment: @nnoitr, No worries, my approach is merely an extension of Pavel Gubkin's nice observation, and definitely he/she deserves the credit.